# Velocity Question from grandparent

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, velocity, relative-motion

My Grandparent asked me this question a few years ago, and I am getting around to giving him an answer, but I don't know the answer. Can anyone help?

> "A pickup truck is speeding along a highway at 60 mph.  One man (c) is standing on the side of the highway at point A. Two men (a and b) are standing in the bed of the pickup truck. As the truck goes by point A, one of the men (a)  standing in the back of the truck throws a baseball at 60 mph out the back and opposite  the direction the truck is going.  My questions are, what will the three men see the ball doing when the baseball leaves the hand of man (a)?"

If possible, please explain with general physics knowledge and nothing too deep.

Comment: Have you seen this [Mythbusters video](https://youtu.be/BLuI118nhzc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ignore air resistance, which would not be great in this situation.. In the frame of reference of the truck, where a and b are, the ball would be seen to have been thrown away from them in a normal trajectory at 60 mph horizontally as it fell vertically towards the ground at 1 g acceleration (about 32 feet per second squared). This is what a and b would see the ball do  if they were standing still on the ground and threw the ball with the same velocity. Observer A, standing still by the road, would see the truck with a and b go by at 60 mph, and he would see the ball fall straight down in front of him. To him the ball would have had its 60 mph  forward velocity cancelled by its 60 mph opposite velocity when it was thrown backwards. So A would see no horizontal movement of the ball, it would only fall vertically, straight downward at 1 g acceleration. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Both the men in the truck will see the ball flying away from them in the truck bed at the speed it was thrown, which is 60 MPH, *relative to the truck* where they are standing. As it departs, it begins to fall towards the ground at the same time it is flying away from them. As such, both will see it describe a parabolic arc *relative to the truck*.

The person standing next to the truck at the instant the one guy throws the ball will see the ball leave his hand at 0 MPH (since 60 MPH - 60 MPH = 0 MPH) and immediately begin to fall in a straight line down towards the ground, while the truck speeds off at 60 MPH.