# What would an outside observer see if I throw a ball in the opposite direction of the train's movement towards a catcher?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, relative-motion

Without taking air resistance into consideration, what would a stationary observer see if I am inside a moving train traveling at 60mph and throw a ball at 60mph opposite the direction of the train? To be clear, the speed of the ball is measured from inside the train, so I would be throwing the ball at 60mph from the point of reference of someone inside the train.

Would they see the catcher catching the ball? I know I would because I'm inside the train. I want to know if light conveys a completely different scenario to an outside observer or not.

Comment: Same scenario for all observers. Even if you shot a laser at the catcher instead of a baseball, all observers everywhere at all relative velocities, even non-inertial observers, would agree on the events and their order - although not their separation in time or what the pitcher was doing at the moment you threw the ball (or laser).

Comment: They would see exactly this - https://youtu.be/ZH7GpYJoptU?t=52. BTW, at speeds of 60mph, you should use standard Newtonian mechanics. Speed of light is a totally useless idea to worry about in this case.

Comment: you will see the ball dripping from the thrower's hands, and the hands of the catcher coming fast to avoid it dropping to the floor

Comment: You mention 'the catcher' in your last paragraph, but you do not mention them anywhere else. How are we meant to know where the catcher is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Velocity Question from grandparent](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580784/velocity-question-from-grandparent)

Answer (score 0):

From the throwers point of view:

60mph is about 27m/s. At that speed the ball would take 0.2 seconds to reach someone 5.4m down the train carriage. They would see the ball reach the catcher in 0.2 seconds and drop by $\frac{1}{2}gt^2$, about 0.2 meters.

From the outside the train point of view:

The ball would be stationary (horizontally) when it left the throwers hand, but begin dropping.  It would drop for 0.2 seconds and fall 0.2 meters during this time until the catcher, appearing to move sideways at 60mph collides with the ball, catching it.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity of the ball with respect to train is -60mph which is the difference of the velocity of  the ball and the train. The velocity of train is also 60mph so the velocity of the ball on ground or stationary observer is 0mph. We can find this by using the concept of relative velocity, where relative velocity is a measure of the speed at which the ball travels.

Comment: You haven't answered the OP's question of what would the outside observer see.